# Cloudflare Caches my javascript files of HTML5 Games and hence game is not loading?

Tags: javascript, html, caching, cloudflare

I am using Cloudflare DNS on one of my HTML 5 Website for caching & running Mario and other games hosted at [hostinger.in](http://hostinger.in).

However the main problem that comes out when I try to load them via my cloudflare website (http://mywish.cf/FullScreenMario-master/mario.html) is that all the HTML 5 Games aren't loaded properly.

However when using them without Cloudflare resources are not cached and game runs properly as on (http://shubhamanand.besaba.com/FullScreenMario-master/mario.html). Can anyone suggest a quick fix as I have tried disabling all the plugins of cloudflare from these pages, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

We wouldn't be impacting HTML, unless you had set a PageRule to cache, so this sounds like a possible issue with Rocket Loader impacting JavaScript. Did you have that feature on?